# Enclosing a set of ellipses within one ellipse

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, conic-sections

Is there an algorithm that takes in a set of ellipses and gives back an ellipse that encloses the original set of ellipses?

Comment: If you just want an ellipse that encloses the given ones, then a giant circle centered at the origin will do.  But you might have meant to enclose the given ones without a lot of extra space.  

Comment: yes, this is what i meant.

Comment: I'm sure there's such an algorithm, and you could try to write one. It shouldn't be too difficult if you define your ellipses as quadratic equations in affine coordinates. Yet I do believe your question is innapropriate for this forum, so you won't receive any other answer. Please read the FAQ.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think the problem of finding a minimum area ellipse enclosing other
ellipses (one interpretation of the question) is as straightforward as it might appear.
I believe it can be solved in polynomial time via convex optimization, but
that might be a heavy hammer, depending on resource constraints.
A good hook into the literature on the topic can be found in this paper:

> S. Jambawalikar and P. Kumar.
>   "A note on Approximate Minimum Volume Enclosing Ellipsoid of Ellipsoids."
>   2008.
>   *Computational Sciences and Its Applications*.
>   ([PDF download](http://compgeom.com/~piyush/papers/emve.pdf); [IEEE link](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=4561253&abstractAccess=no&userType=inst))

[image: MinEllipseEllipses]

Comment: Inspired by Joseph's picture, I would suggest the following approach: Build a convex hull approximation of the union of ellipses, then apply a scale transformation to the hull to make it circular roughly, find the smallest enclosing circle, then invert the transformation.  Gerhard "Often Inspired By Joseph's Pictures" Paseman, 2013.01.23

Comment: Nothing in the OP question pointed towards a minimizing area ellipse. I maintain it is easy to find a simple algorithm fulfiling the OP question, even with some optimization regarding the size of the enclosing ellipse. Anyway...

Answer (score 6):

Here is a link to semidefinite programming code for solving this type of problem (for ellipsoids):

[CVX based solution of Min volume covering elllipsoids](http://cvxr.com/cvx/examples/cvxbook/Ch08_geometric_probs/html/min_vol_union_ellip.html)